# Xamarin: The variable 'session' is assigned but its value is never used

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have this error message. I'm creating a Xamarin.ios table view app. If anyone can help me thanks in advance.

```
    public partial class SessionsViewController : UITableViewController
    {
        public SessionsViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            var sessionManager = SessionsManager.Create();
            TableView.Source = new SessionsTableViewSource(sessionManager.Sessions);
        }
    }

    public class SessionsManager
    {
        private static SessionsManager _instance = null;
        public SessionData[] Sessions;
        public static SessionsManager Create()
        {
            if (_instance == null) _instance = new SessionsManager();
            return _instance;
        }
        internal SessionsManager()
        {
            SessionData[] sessions = new SessionData[5] // receive the error here.{
            new Data("1", "Title1", "speaker1", "desc1", DateTime.Today, true),
            new Data("2", "Title2", "speaker2", "desc2", DateTime.Today, false),
            new Data("3", "Title3", "speaker3", "desc3", DateTime.Today, false),
            new Data("4", "Title4", "speaker4", "desc4", DateTime.Today, true),
            new Data("5", "Title5", "speaker5", "desc5", DateTime.Today, true)
        };
    }
```

I have this error message. I'm creating a Xamarin.ios table view app. If anyone can help me thanks in advance

Comment: remove the "new" keyword...

Comment: Hi Gus, I removed the keyword "new" and now i'm getting a warning.

Comment: Warning CS0219: The variable `sessions' is assigned but its value is never used (CS0219).

Comment: aaand that means you're not using it for nothing... if you use it the warning will disappear.

Comment: Also the app won't run. System.NullReferenceException has been thrown object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Add a new question, and be more specific, programmers aren't fortune-tellers with crystal balls...

Comment: The variable 'sessions' is assigned but it's value is never used. SessionData[] sessions = new SessionData[5]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is apparently going to ask us to explain every compiler error and warning even when the text of the error message should be comprehensible.

Comment: No i'm not i just need help with this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign your array to the Sessions member rather than to a local variable.

Try

```
internal SessionsManager()
{
    Sessions = new SessionData[5] {
        new Data("1", "Title1", "speaker1", "desc1", DateTime.Today, true),
        new Data("2", "Title2", "speaker2", "desc2", DateTime.Today, false),
        new Data("3", "Title3", "speaker3", "desc3", DateTime.Today, false),
        new Data("4", "Title4", "speaker4", "desc4", DateTime.Today, true),
        new Data("5", "Title5", "speaker5", "desc5", DateTime.Today, true)
    };
}
```